# Element of a splitting field that can be construct using ruler and compas

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Looking at the splitting field over $\Bbb{Q}$ of $X^5-2$ which is $D:=\Bbb{Q}(e^{2ik\pi/5},2^{1/5}).$

What element of $D$ can be construct using ruler and compas ? For the reals I know it means that the degree of the slipping field is a power of $2$, but what about complexes elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note $\zeta_5 = e^{2ik\pi/5}$. You have
$$[\mathbb Q(\zeta_5):\mathbb Q]=4, \ [\mathbb Q(\sqrt[5]{2}):\mathbb Q]=5.$$

As $4, 5$ are coprime, $[\mathbb Q(\zeta_5,\sqrt[5]{2}):\mathbb Q]=20$. Therefore the Galois group $\text{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\zeta_5,\sqrt[5]{2})/\mathbb Q)$ is of order $20$.

Now, a complex $z$ number is [constructible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number) over $\mathbb Q$ (like for a real) if and only if $[\mathbb Q(z):\mathbb Q]$ is a power of $2$. *This was one of your question.*

So we're left to find the subfields $K \subseteq \mathbb Q(\zeta_5,\sqrt[5]{2})$ such that $[K:\mathbb Q] \in \{2,4\}$.

**Suppose that that $[K:\mathbb Q] =4$**

Then according to [Fundamental theorem of Galois theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Galois_theory)
$$(\text{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\zeta_5,\sqrt[5]{2})/\mathbb Q):G)=4$$ where $G=\text{Aut}(\mathbb Q(\zeta_5,\sqrt[5]{2})/K)$. That means that $G$ is a $5$-Sylow of $\text{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\zeta_5,\sqrt[5]{2}))$. According to Sylow theorems, there is only one $5$-Sylow and therefore one subfield $K$ having the required properties which is in fact $\mathbb Q(\zeta_5)$. The associated constructible number provides a construction of the pentagon.

**Suppose that that $[K:\mathbb Q] =2$**

*To be done.*

Comment: Thank you +1, does the case $[K:Q]=2$ can be done with Galois theory too?

Comment: Yes. The Galois group of $K$ is $G\cong \Bbb Z/4\ltimes \Bbb Z/5$ and you have to identity the subgroups of order $10$.

Comment: Isn't $D_5$ ? But in term of subfield ?

Comment: $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{5})$ is one of the subfield.

Comment: How do you prove that $\sqrt{5}\in D$? There is also $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_5+\zeta_5^{-1})$ is degree $2$ over $\Bbb{Q}.$ which is contained in $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_5)$ so it's not really interesting.

Comment: To complete the answer: If $[K:\Bbb{Q}]=2$, then, as you observed, $K$ is the fixed field of an order 10 subgroup of the big Galois group $H$. As the 5-Sylow $G$ is a normal subgroup of $H$, such subgroups are, by the correspondence principle, in 1-1 relation between the order 2 subgroups of the quotient $H/G$. But $H/G\simeq Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_5)/\Bbb{Q})\simeq \Bbb{Z}_4$, i.e. a cyclic group. Therefore there is only one such subgroup, and consequently only a single quadratic intermediate field.

Comment: Observe that $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt5)=\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_5+\zeta_5^{-1})$. If $u=\zeta_5+\zeta_5^{-1}$, then
$$u^2+u=1+\sum_{j=-2}^2\zeta_5^j=1+0=1,$$
so by the quadratic formula
$$u=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}2.$$ Here the plus sign applies.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Brillant. I realized this morning that $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_5+zeta_5^{-1})=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$. Merci!